# @test with priority fails to run the correct test if there are multiple classes

Tags: annotations, testng

I have a testng.xml file and i have three classes and all three have tests with priority from 1 to 4(@Test(priority=1 to 4)). On running it the tests with priority 1 from different classes run first and affect the flow of my test.What kind of testng annotation can I use to avoid this?

`@Test(priority=1)` given in multiple classes

Comment: You should share your Testng.xml code, it is depends on how you have defined it

Answer (score 2):

use preserve order

```
 <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

So that all classes specified in testng.xml will run in specified order and then in each class methods will run as per priority.

Answer (score 0):

In testng, the order of the classes mentioned in the testng.xml doesn't matter if you have the priority set in the tests inside those classes. The tests will run according to the priorities (priority=1 tests will run first and then priority=2 and further on).

To solve the above issue, you need to remove the priorities from the tests inside the classes and then put the classes in the testng in the order you want to execute those classes and put `<preserve-order="true">` in the testng xml.

If you want to run the tests inside a class also in a particular order, then you can use `dependsOnMethods` between the tests mentioned inside the class like:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"parentTest"})
public void childTest() {       
}

@Test
public void parentTest() {      
}
```

In the above case, when the parentTest() pass only then the childTest() will execute.